# Shows One Shell User, But More Connection Via SSH Port

Tags: ssh, netstat

I've just run the command on my server

```
netstat -atnp
```

It shows 2 established connection via SSH Port, but when I run the command

```
w
```

It shows only 1 shell user. Is there anything I need to worry about? If so, what could it be? & how to find out about what it's about?

Comment: is it possible that one of the SSH connections is outside connection? if not, [edit] your question and add the output of `w` and `netstat -atnp | grep -i ssh`

Comment: @Yaron what do you mean by outside connection?

Comment: Is it possible that the user logged into the system, ssh from this machine into another machine? is it possible that the *ssh connection* is outside the machine?

Comment: If I misunderstood please just tell me and I will remove my answer. If you could provide output `netstat -atnp | grep -F ":22"` it would help to understand

Comment: ssh transport can be used for things other than a shell login; most obviously sftp and scp, but other protocols can layer on top of an ssh connection as well.

Comment: @Yaron don't you think it could be a security rusk to share the output of command such as netstat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you shouldn't be worry.
`netstat -a` will show every socket (open, listenning, closed...) wo there's probably only your listening ssh deamon plus your current connection.
In your specific case, I would use `lsof -i TCP:22` which is in my opinion far more readable.

```
lsof -i TCP:22
COMMAND   PID               USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd     9760               root    3r  IPv4 20888000      0t0  TCP internalIP:ssh->RemoteIP:58828 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd     9765               another 3u  IPv4 20888000      0t0  TCP InternalIP:ssh->RemoteIP:58828 (ESTABLISHED)
sshd    10348               root    3u  IPv4 12609613      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd    10348               root    4u  IPv6 12609615      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)    enter code here
```

In this output you can see the two open connection and the 2 listenning in IPv4 and IPv6.

**Edit 1:**
If you're using sudo, it will be virtually like having 2 SSH connections opened. And using `who` show you will only see your username and not the root logged-in. If you have done a `sudo su -`:

```
who
username pts/0        2017-04-04 13:19 (MY_PUB_IP)
sudo su -
:~# who
username pts/0        2017-04-04 13:19 (MY_PUB_IP)
:~#
```

Comment: Well it does show more details, but I got even confused.  Actually it shows more established connection on ssh than via netstat. FYI, the server is a virtualized environment, and is most probably connected to a centralized mgmt console. Does that info help?

Comment: @Sollosa you should edit your answer with more details output so I can help. BTW, if you see several ssh connection from same ephemeral port (here 58828), it means that you only have one SSH connection.